# Expected value of absolute difference of random variables

Tags: self-study, expected-value

Given two continuous random variables X and Y with joint pdf

> $f(x,y)=1$ if $0 \leq X \leq 1$ and $0 \leq y<1 $

I want to find $E(|X-Y|)$

What I have done so far is to calculate marginal $F_x$ and $F_y$ which both are 1 in my case and then using the marginal to calculate $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ but I think that I am making some mistake as I think that the expected value should be positive for all cases where $X<Y$.
What would be the general recommended method to solve problems like this?

Comment: Calculating the marginal densities does not help because $|X-Y|$ is a function of _both_ random variables and its expectation must be calculated from the _joint_ density of $X$ and $Y$. Also, $E|X-Y|]$ cannot be determined from $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$ or from $E|X|]$ and $E[|Y|]$. Instead, use the method suggested to you by @Alexey.

Comment: I second Dilip's advice: treat this as a pure mathematical problem of (double) integration over the joint density, with the decomposition that Alexey suggested and in any case, don't try to think "intuitively" in terms of probabilities because you will most likely be misled -the fact that the underlying generating mechanism involves uniform random variables and so "equiprobable" situations, is the standard bait for an "intuition trap" that usually leads to mistaken conclusions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to divide your area $[0, 1]$ to two: where $X > Y$ and where $Y \geq X$. Next you can simplify $|X - Y|$ in each area and take integral over each area.